# ScriptUtils.ASPForm errors

Tags: object, vbscript, asp-classic

i am trying to upload big file to the database SQL using the sample code from
[Upload - large files to MS SQL Server using a HexString property and UPDATETEXT SQL statement](http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/sa259.htm) but when i run the code i am getting the following error

> Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'
> Server.CreateObject Failed

which is in

```
Set Form = Server.CreateObject("ScriptUtils.ASPForm")
```

from where i can get this dll for free to be able to register it?
or is there any other solution ?

thank you

Comment: It looks like it isn't free - sorry.  http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/lc2.htm

Comment: If you want a free option look at freeaspupload - it's a class file rather than a component. The website has disappeared, but you can still find it on the internet archive https://web.archive.org/web/20121014153715/http://freeaspupload.net/